# 回答の並び順が票数と一致しない

Tags: バグ

質問に対して複数の回答が付いた場合、[ツアーの説明](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)を読む限りは「票数が多いものから順に表示される」と理解していましたが、

> 一番役に立つ回答をすぐに読めるように、点数が高いものほど先頭に表示されます。

実際にいくつかの質問を開いてみると、承認がされた回答は最上位に表示されるものの、それ以外の回答の並び順が票数とは関係ないように見えます。

なお、本家SOについては同じ状況(票数とは無関係な並び)ですが、その他Exchange Networkのサイトについてはいくつか覗いた限りは(ツアーの説明通り)票数に応じた並びとなっていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 回答のソート順を選ぶことができます。ウェブ版だと回答群の右上に選択欄があり、ここから「票」を選ばないと票数順にはなりません。

   > [image: 「アクティブ」「古い順」「票」]
2. また、承認された回答が自己回答かどうかによって、上に来るかどうかが変わります。自己回答は承認されたとしても上には来ず、ソート順に沿って配置されます。参考: [Vote ordering of accepted answers has changed: Accepted below top voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6365/341401)

これらで解決しませんでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます、完全に見落としていました。